# Change order status with direct raw sql

Tags: magento-1.7, order-status, sql

Is it possible to achieve this easilly with updating the sales_flat_order status info? 
Or is this information defined in other db tables?

Answer (score 4):

You can update values using

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order` SET `status` = 'Your status code here' WHERE `entity_id` = 99;
```

But for consistency you have to change the value of `status`  in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table also. That one is used to display the orders grid.

But be careful. You may have to change the `state` field also. The `status` may depend on the `state` field. Each status is allowed for one specific state.
You can check the relations between state and status from `System->Order statuses`.
Before changing anything I recommend a backup.

Comment: I would forgot the sales_flat_order_grid without your advice. Thank you.

Comment: Also remember that this will not trigger any Magento logic that's usually called when the status changes, but this is  probably what you want.

Comment: @marius:   after changed order status from canceled to processing, can't able to do take invoice. how can I get the invoice?